# AbstractContextSwitchRoute decorator fails on 6.4.17

Tags: shopware, shopware6

updating from 6.4.10 to 6.4.17 I get an error on a `ContextSwitchRoute` decorator I wrote.
Here's the error I get during a context switch (changing payment method on checkout page).
Anyone has a clue of the reason?
If I de-activate the decorator, of course, everything works.

```
Argument 1 passed to Shopware\Storefront\Controller\ContextController::__construct() must be an instance of Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannel\ContextSwitchRoute, instance of Lp\PickupPoint\Decorator\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannel\ContextSwitchRoute given
```

In services.xml:

```
<service id="Lp\PickupPoint\Decorator\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannel\ContextSwitchRouteDecorator"
             decorates="Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannel\ContextSwitchRoute"
             public="true">
        <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataValidator" key="$validator" />
        <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextPersister" key="$contextPersister"/>
        <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher" key="$eventDispatcher" />
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,
I was extending `AbstractContextSwitchRoute` in the class, I have to extend `ContextSwitchRoute` as stated in `services.xml` and call

```
parent::__construct($validator, $contextPersister, $eventDispatcher);
```

in the constructor.
Now everything works as expected.

Comment: please mark your own answer as accepted. It helps users who come here with intent to answer unanswered questions.